# How do I use an Access 2003 mde with Access 2007 and keep my custom menus/toolbars?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2003

Please describe the exact steps required to use a compiled Access 2003 mdb with the Access 2007 runtime and retain my custom menus and toolbars so that they look the same as they did with the 2003 runtime. I've tried following the various incomplete instructions around the web, but I either end up with my menus/toolbars on the ribbon's ugly looking Add-ins tab, or they fail to appear altogether.

Answer (score 2):

See Jeff Conrad's page [How do I get my existing legacy menu bars and toolbars to work in Access 2007? Right now they all show up on the Add-Ins tab.](http://accessjunkie.com/faq_31.aspx)

BTW the probably two best sites on converting to Access 2007 are http://allenbrowne.com/Access2007.html and http://accessjunkie.com/faq2007.aspx

Comment: This is one of the suggestions I already tried. It doesn't work. What you get from this is four copies of the toolbar and any menu option that matches an old Access menu option (like 'file') doesn't work when you click on it.

Comment: Something wierd is going on because that's worked fine for me.  Mind you I don't use built in menus much so what I do is quite ismple.

Comment: I experimented with this a bit more. I have some startup code that enables or disables commandbar controls depending on user preferences and permissions. Accessing the Enabled and Visible properties of the Commandbar or its child controls causes duplicate menus and/or toolbars to appear. if I disable all of my startup logic related to the Commandbar object the instructions in the link you provided Do work. My apologies. Still, changing Commandbar Visible or Enabled properties should not cause my menus to duplicate. One problem solved and on to the next. Curse this wretched ribbon.

Comment: Excellent, glad to see you're making progress.  As far as curses go, well, I had to chuckle, sorry.